# Extracting data attributes from elements in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a script in console to display only data inside elements from a html page:

```
<tr class="pl-video yt-uix-tile " data-video-id="AAAAAAAA" data-title="BBBBBBBBBBBB"  ...
```

The data I want to extract is inside `data-video-id` and `data-title`. There is a simple way to do it in chrome console or using some plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in console

```
$('.pl-video').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).data('video-id'));
   console.log($(this).data('title'));
})
```

Edited by baumi: removing unnecessary dot (".") from selector.

Comment: I got: **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.pl-video.' is not a valid selector.(…)**

Comment: You entered '.pl-video.' when correct is '.pl-video' (without last dot).
Thank you very much, it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
console.log($('.pl-video').attr('data-video-id'));
console.log($('.pl-video').attr('data-title'));
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to access `data-*` attributes

```js
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
console.log(tr.dataset.videoId, tr.dataset.title)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="pl-video yt-uix-tile " data-video-id="AAAAAAAA" data-title="BBBBBBBBBBBB"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great, it extracts the first <tr>

How to code a loop to get all instances from entire page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$('.plvideo').each(function(){                                                                console.log($(this).attr('data-video-id'));
              console.log($(this).attr('data-title'));
})